# Is there a shortcut to deleting all in one table not in another?

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2014

Are there any shortcuts for deleting everything in one table that does not exist in the second?

I know I can do this:

```
    DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT)
    DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INT)

    INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
    INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (3),(4)

    DELETE t1
        FROM @Table1 t1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Table2 t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID)

    SELECT * FROM @Table1
```

However, I have over 600 columns, so you can see why I might be reluctant to go that route if there's another way. What I WANT to do would look like this:

```
    DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT)
    DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INT)

    INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
    INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (3),(4)

    DELETE @Table1
        EXCEPT SELECT * FROM @Table2
```

That EXCEPT has been very handy in dealing with this project I'm working on, but I guess it's limited.

Comment: well you first statement would be what you wanted, assuming the ID is the link between the two. Are you saying that there is no unique key that would join these two tables or you only want to unique rows regardles of key value?

Comment: Right, no unique key in the second table, just in the first. That unique ID is a historical record, so it doesn't apply in the second, which is a selection of current data.

Comment: What is the relevance of *I have over 600 columns*? You are joining on `ID`. Do you want to join on *any* of the 600? Something else?

Comment: Right. I would have to join on all 600+ columns. Also, "would have to" is now "had to". It's fine, really. Just wondered if there's a more efficient way.

Comment: I think you could just truncate table1 and select * from table2... same concept here. You want table1 to look just like table2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this:

```
DELETE FROM @Table1 WHERE  BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) NOT IN(SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) FROM @Table2);
```

But be carefull, if your table contains **float** data types. In very rare cases wrong checksum may be calculated. But, these cases are rare and random, no problems will remain after second delete iteration.

Comment: Interesting idea, but checksum collisions are unavoidable

Comment: Fascinating. How does it do with NULL?

Comment: Would be fine:
BINARY_CHECKSUM can be applied over a list of expressions, and returns the same value for a specified list. BINARY_CHECKSUM applied over any two lists of expressions returns the same value if the corresponding elements of the two lists have the same type and byte representation. For this definition, null values of a specified type are considered to have the same byte representation.

Comment: Well, it still wasn't easy. But I definitely feel like this was the shortest way to success, so thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
DELETE t1
FROM @Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: what if only the ID are the same, and values from the rest 599 are different, still do not want to delete?

Comment: Try to imagine: you dont know column names at all. There is no PK or column count known (f.e. 600 cols...)

Comment: @LONG I may have misunderstood the question. I'm waiting for OP to answer my comment on the Q

Comment: @Bohemian, ya, but I think what op was asking is how to skip putting each column in that query xD

Comment: @Juozas I would ask then, how is `@Table2` being populated - surely *that* is the time and place to do the delete from `@Table1`. I now think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Definitely XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was about the case, when t1 and t2 tables are the same, and joined corressponding cols, when deciding deletion.

Ok, now about the other situation: your @table1 column [ID] can by joined with any     unknown @table2 column. You can solve 600+ cols problem using XML:

```
DELETE FROM @Table1 WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [ID]) NOT IN
(
    SELECT
        [col].[value]('(.)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT [xml] = (CONVERT(XML, (SELECT * FROM @Table2 FOR XML PATH('t2'))))
    ) AS [t2]
    CROSS APPLY [t2].[xml].[nodes]('t2/*') AS [tab]([col])
);
```

Comment: P.S. little bug fixed: ('t2') > ('t2/*')